# How can we change the value of a p tag present in v2 div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we change the value of a p tag present in v2 div?

```
<div id="v1">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique within a page otherwise use `class` attribute.

Comment: Please explain upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use unique `id` to each `p` and change between `innerHTML`

```js
var c1=document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML;
var c2=document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = c2;
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = c1;
```

```html
<div id="v1">
<div class="flow">
    <p id="content1">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
<div class="flow">
    <p id="content2">Hello of 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. And yes ID should be unique.

```js
document.querySelector('#v2 div p').innerHTML = 'changed';
```

```html
<div id="v1">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid syntax and as such generally advised against to have multiple uses of the one ID on a page, but here is how you’d do it:

```
<div id="v1">
    <div id="flow">
        <p id="content">Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
    <div id="flow">
        <p id="content">Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("v2").getElementById("content").innerText = "Some new text";
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, remove duplicate `id`s from your code. No two elements withing a page should have same `id`. You may use `class` attribute if you wants to have multiple elements in same group. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme) post for more details.
- Second, use `querySelector()` method to get a reference to the desired element and override its `textContent` property with the content you wants to add.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('#v2 p.content');

para.textContent = 'World';
```

```html
<div id="v1">
  <div class="flow">
      <p class="content">Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
  <div class="flow">
      <p class="content">Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**References:**

- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="v1">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="v2">
<div id="flow">
    <p id="content">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
```

This will be work for all the p and nested p inside v2 div.

```
   <script>
traverse=(node)=>{
      for(let i=0;i<node.childElementCount;i++){
          if(node.children[i].nodeName=="p"){
            node.children[i].innerHTML=`Your HTML`;
          }
          if(node.children[i].childElementCount>0)
          {
              traverse(node.children[i]);
          }

      }
    }
    traverse(document.getElementById("v2"));
</script>
```